# Retrieving manufacturer element in Magento using SOAP

Tags: xml, magento, soap, custom-attributes

Have spent too many hours on this, my head hurts... I need to get the manufacturer (custom?) attribute value in Magento.

An XML dump of the site shows me only one element with these two manufacturer values:

        ...

```
    <row>
            <field name="value_id">7</field>
            <field name="option_id">7</field>
            <field name="store_id">0</field>
            <field name="value">Hungry Gerbil</field>
    </row>
    <row>
            <field name="value_id">8</field>
            <field name="option_id">6</field>
            <field name="store_id">0</field>
            <field name="value">Hungry Hamster</field>
    </row>
    ...
```

and I can obtain the option_id (7) through a SOAP call:

<manufacturer>7</manufacturer>

which I want to convert to:

<manufacturer>Hungry Gerbil</manufacturer>

The problem is that in practice I would not have access to the xml dump, so I need to retrieve the eav_attribute_option_value data using a SOAP call.
I have gone through all 138 operation names in [magento_root] using this call:

```
    $apicalls = array();
    $i = 0; 

    // Optional filters
    $filters = array('sku' => array('neq'=>''));

    // Initial call to get a list of product IDs
    $products = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list',array($filters));

    // Loop through product IDs and grab attributes & images
    foreach ($products as $product){
        $apicalls[$i] = array('catalog_product_attribute.info', $product['product_id']);
        $i++;
     }
```

So I am assuming that whatever is the correct substitution of "catalog_product_attribute.info" in the example above will result in an array which includes the eav_attribute_option_value data. Or I am looking in the wrong place...

It would help us all if Magento was better documented, in the meantime any suggestions welcome.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

You got attribute value id. Now you should get label using [catalog_product_attribute.options](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product_attribute#catalog_product_attribute.options).